Unable to post anything on Stack Overflow
I am not able to post my question on Stack Overflow. It just says

An error occurred submitting the post

but there is absolutely no information about the error. I tried to strip the post of all code and still it is not letting me post. What should I do? Is my account locked or something?
I am trying to post this question to see what is causing the problem. I will update it to include code and the actual question if this question makes it through.

Try browsing to the captcha page, solve the captcha, then post your question.

I have been trying to post the above question by modifying it in many ways since several hours but SO is not accepting it and not telling me what is wrong. I am at my wits end here. Please help.

Please read my first comment, and also don't post the question as comment.

Browsing to the captcha page and then trying to post did not help. I did not post the question here to get an answer to that question. I posted the question here to explain what I am trying to post because it is not letting me post it in the question content.

Your account appears to be fine and the problem on SE/SO side. Ever since they moved to CloudFlare, I see huge increase in reports of users getting blocked, that's just another part of it.

Anyway you can check the error status code with the browser's network tab, when you try to submit.

I see you were able to post, please share what you did, if anything, for the sake of others having same problem.

Yes, I tried posting again and the post went through. I didn't do anything different. It is the same content I have been trying to post for past several hours. I have absolutely no clue what changed.

@Priyshrm maybe the traffic originating from your network or volume of spam decreased.

Likely cause
